# Is there a way to adjust routing based on headers in Elysia?

Tags: routes, http-headers, bun, elysiajs

I'm attempting to change my routing based on header values.
For example, if an incoming request contains an accept header of `application/json`, I want to call one set of routes to return JSON data, but if it does not have that header, I want to fall back to serving static files.

According to [the docs](https://elysiajs.com/concept/life-cycle.html), both the Request and Parse steps come before the routing, and since there isn't an `onRouting`-type method, my assumption would be to get the headers in either Request or Parse, and adjust *something* that will affect the routing.

I thought about perhaps using a custom method, so for example if the accept header was `application/json`, then I could change the method to, say, `JSON` and then define the rest of my routes like `.route('JSON', () => doTheThing())`. But of course the request's method is read-only, so I can't really do that.